# How to wait to render page with express, while API grabs data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to load data from the twitter api, getting user information and save that in a temporary array. That array will then be loaded on the page for viewing. The array is getting loaded by the API call, but it doesn't display.

I think I need to use an asynchronous thing like React or Angular, not sure. Would love some input!

```
function getUserIds (userId) {
    T.get('statuses/retweeters/ids', { id: userId }, function (err, data, response) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.ids.length; i++){
            ids.push(data.ids[i]);
        }
        getUserInfo();
    });
}
function getUserInfo() {
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        T.get('users/lookup', { user_id: ids[i] }, function (err, data, response) { 
            names.push(data[0].screen_name);
            pics.push(data[0].profile_image_url_https);
            console.log(names); 
        });
    }
    res.render('display', {names: names, pics:pics});
}
```

Comment: We can't really help with out seeing your code.  **Questions about code need to show the relevant code.**  It is likely you are just not properly handling the async nature of the API call, but that's just a guess.  We can tell for sure and suggest the exact code to fix it if you show us your actual code.  That's how things work best here.  You don't need a whole framework just to handle one API call.

Comment: Sorry added more background. The names and pics array is getting filled, but when sent to the display.ejs file, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are running `ids.length` async calls and those will finish some time in the future.  You have to render your page only when they are all done.  But, your `for` loop is synchronous so you are calling `res.render()` before any of them have finished.  In addition, your `T.get()` calls may finish in any order (if that matters).

I would normally use promises for coordinating multiple asynchronous operations since it is a very, very good tool for that.  But, if you aren't using promises, here's a simple technique to test when you have all your results back:

```
function getUserInfo() {
    var names = [];
    var pics = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        T.get('users/lookup', { user_id: ids[i] }, function (err, data, response) { 
            if (err) {
                // decide what to display if you get an API error
                names.push("unknown due to API error");
            } else {
                names.push(data[0].screen_name);
                pics.push(data[0].profile_image_url_https);
                console.log(names); 
            }
            if (names.length === ids.length) {
                res.render('display', {names: names, pics:pics});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As I said above, this does not necessarily collect the results in order.  If you need them in order, then you could do something like this:

```
function getUserInfo() {
    var names = new Array(ids.length);
    var pics = new Array(ids.length);
    var doneCntr = 0;
    ids.forEach(function(id, i) {
        T.get('users/lookup', { user_id: id }, function (err, data, response) { 
            if (err) {
                // decide what to display if you get an API error
                names[i] = "unknown due to API error";
            } else {
                names[i] = data[0].screen_name;
                pics[i] = data[0].profile_image_url_https;
            }
            ++doneCntr;
            if (doneCntr === ids.length) {
                res.render('display', {names: names, pics: pics});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

My preferred solution would to be to use `Promise.all()` and use a promisified version of `T.get()`.

Comment: That make's a lot of sense to me! Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: @Jackgisel - I added an implementation that keeps the results in order.